# How to downgrade log.message.format.version in Kafka 2.5.0

Tags: apache-kafka

One of our Apache Kafka clusters has the following properties

```
    "inter.broker.protocol.version": "2.5",
    "log.message.format.version": "2.5"
```

We are using [Brooklin](https://github.com/linkedin/brooklin) to replicate data between Kafka clusters,
**Brooklin** works with an old Kafka client and it can't consume records with such an advanced version. We tested **Brooklin** with  `"log.message.format.version" to "2.2"` and it works well.

Is it possible to downgrade `"log.message.format.version" to "2.2"?`
What will be the effect on the other producers and consumers?
I couldn't find a guide in the apache documentation.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible to go to `2.2`; it is not possible to go below `2.1`

https://kafka.apache.org/25/documentation.html#upgrade

Comment: thanks, 
Will this downgrade be seamless to the consumers of the cluster?

Comment: I've not personally tried to downgrade, but there's no settings to modify on the consumers, so I'd assume so. You will of course need to restart the brokers, so you might experience some disconnection errors... You could also migrate Brooklyn to MirrorMaker2 instead

Comment: thanks, I will set up a test environment and update here.